# nouveau FAULT on Macbook Pro w/ Debian on boot

Tags: debian, boot, macintosh, nouveau

I have a 2010 13inch MacBook Pro currently running Debian 9 with no real noticeable or detrimental issues.

That said, after getting past the Mac startup tone, I see the following errors:

```
[ 12.283961] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000B07f FAULT at 100c18
[ 12.367005] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000B07e FAULT at 100c1c
```

Sometimes there are more than two lines, but generally it only hangs on them for a couple of seconds before showing all the normal [ OK ] lines.

I understand that nouveau is something about the NVidia drivers for MBPs but I can't seem to find anything on SE about errors like mine. Everything I read seems to mention crashes, but I watch videos all the time without any crashes or issues whatsoever.

I'm just looking to resolve whatever issues are causing these errors. 
I honestly cannot recall if I ever installed any Nvidia drivers on this laptop or not, it's been a while.

Comment: If you'd googled nouveau, you'd realize that this is an open source driver for Nvidia. If these warnings are not causing any grief for you, it's safest to leave them alone. Otherwise you may want to engage in an exhausting back and forth with the distro maintainers or the kernel driver team in a hope they would look into that. Your call.

Comment: @ajeh gotcha, I was worried that something was broken but not visibly so. But if you're saying it might not be worth the effort to simply remove some benign warnings, then yeah I'll just leave it alone. Thanks.